# Django: syncdb not creating new table after dump is loaded

Tags: python, django, postgresql

tl;dr: We want to add a new table to the database, without losing previous data.

First we took a dump of the database using:

```
$ psql -h localhost dbname > dump_file
```

Then we loaded it to our local db. This is working fine.

**Problem starts:**
On adding a new model to models.py, syncdb doesn't create the table. However, if we create a new db (by deleting the data and running syncdb), it shows up as a created table.

This is surprising, because we don't think that adding a new table is a 'schema migration' that syncdb cannot handle. Hence, we don't think South will help here.

Is there something I'm missing/getting wrong?

This is what our code looks like:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    # attributes

class A(models.Model):
    # attributes

class B(models.Model):
    a_fk = models.ForeignKey(A)
    # more attributes

class ProblemModel(models.Model)
    p_fk = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    a_fk = models.ForeignKey(A)
    b_fk = models.ForeignKey(B)
```

The output for the concerned table using the command:

```
$ ./manage.py sqlall appname
```

is:

```
CREATE TABLE "appname_problemmodel" (
"id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
"p_fk" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "appname_person" ("p_fk") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
"a_fk" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "appname_a" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
"b_fk" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "appname_b" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
)
```

Django version 1.5.1

ProblemModel is the new model we're trying to add.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Is there any other `ForeignKey` definition in your new tables? May be there is a problem about `NULL`able columns in other tables so Django can not create related FK relations. Also checking FK relations before creating the tables may cause problems if data-filled tables have some un-indexed columns(?). I am not sube about the both, but there can be a problem because about those. Do `syncdb`comment executes and finishes or it hangs and waits? Also, did you check your error logs?

Comment: Taking a wild guess here, but is the actual name of your `ProblemClass` a combination of the names of the other 3 model classes?

Comment: Which model class did you add?  Please provide step by step instructions on how to recreate the issue.  And what django version.

Comment: @zsquare: nope, completely different

Comment: @FallenAngel: 1. These are the only FKs in the new table (ProblemModel). 2. The data-filled tables are currently not indexed, I'm not sure what you mean by "checking FK relations before creating tables"

Comment: @FallenAngel: Where are the error logs located? I've not used Django very long. :/

Comment: @user558061 - I've edited two things. However, I don't think I can recreate the problem without the actual dump that we took. Unless you can suggest something?

Comment: Has the db a table with name `app_problemmodel` ?

Comment: @srusskih yes, I have updated the question with the result of 'sqlall' command for the table in question

Comment: _This is surprising, because we don't think that adding a new table is a 'schema migration' that syncdb cannot handle. Hence, we don't think South will help here._ - But it __is__ a schema migration and South __will__ help.

Comment: @Kimvais: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I'm newish to South as well. Is it possible for you to direct me to a link which would outline this? I'm on the South docs, but I honestly don't know what to look for. :/

Comment: @merlinsbrain what happens when you start your syncdb, is it complated or is it just keep running without finishing? Is there any other FK relation from these models to some other existing model in your database with some data in it? And finally, did you try it while your system is running, because postgresql waits for your db tables to become available before creating references to other tables and if those other tables (linked with FKs) are in use, postgresql starts to wait for them to become available and that may last for a very long time. So, syncdb process keeps running or it finishes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all Your data restore command have wrong input symbol. It should be :-

```
$ psql -h localhost dbname < dump_file
```

[django-admin-flush] (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/django-admin/#=django-admin-flush) has an example of getting database to previous state with options - * --no-initial-data*.

It is best to use south with following command execution -

```
('python manage.py migrate --no-initial-data')
('python manage.py syncdb')
```

To restore data to database you can use dump with admin.py or directly use your 
database command.

Answer (score 0):

> Hence, we don't think South will help here.

Yes it will, just use [it](http://south.aeracode.org/) - the [official documentation](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/convertinganapp.html#converting-an-app) should get you started.